# ¿Como hacer operaciones con los atributos de un objeto dentro de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy estudiando sobre la POO y en la escuela nos dejaron un problema y en una parte nos pide lo siguiente:

Se requiere automatizar una máquina despachadora de productos, la cual se considera un almacén, y se requiere contar con
las siguientes funciones:
• Agregar producto: código, nombre, precio, cantidad. Si el producto no existe en la lista, se debe agregar; si ya existe, se
debe incrementar la cantidad de producto agregado.

lo que yo quiero hacer es un método que pida una instancia de Producto y dentro poner un if que en caso de que la instancia tenga el mismo código que otro se le sume la cantidad de la instancia pero esa es la parte que se me complica pues no se como hacerlo.

Si alguien tiene una mejor manera de realizar la actividad estaría muy agradecido de que me lo mostrara.

Aquí el código:

```html
public class Producto
{
    public String nombre;
    public int codigo, cantidad;
    public double precio;
    
    public Producto(){
        
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }
    
    public void setNombre(String _nombre){
        this.nombre = _nombre;
    }
    
    public int getCodigo(){
        return this.codigo;
    }
    
    public void setCodigo(int _codigo){
        this.codigo = _codigo;
    }
    
    public int getCantidad(){
        return this.cantidad;
    }
    
    public void setCantidad(int _cantidad){
        this.cantidad = _cantidad;
    }
    
    public double getPrecio(){
        return this.precio;
    }
    
    public void setPrecio(double _precio){
        this.precio = _precio;
    }
}

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Maquina
{
    private List<Producto> productos, productosVendidos;
    private Date fechaCorte;
    private double totalVentas;
    
    public Maquina(){
        this.productos = new ArrayList<Producto>();
    }
    
    public List<Producto> getProductos(){
        return this.productos;
    }
    
    public void agregarProducto(Producto producto){
        if (this.productos.contains(producto.codigo)) {
           this.productos.producto.getCantidad() += producto.cantidad;
        } else {   this.productos.add(producto);
     }
    }
    
    public void despacharProducto(int codigo){
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para el problema que planteas yo utilizaría el tipo de dato "HashMap" para almacenar los productos. La key sería el codigo de producto y el value, el objeto producto en sí.

En el método "agregarProducto" compruebas si el producto ya existe o no usando su código.

Tu clase máquina quedaría así:

```
    public class Maquina
    {
        private List<Producto> productosVendidos;
        private Map<Integer, Producto> listaProductos;
        private Date fechaCorte;
        private double totalVentas;

        public Maquina(){
            this.listaProductos = new HashMap<Integer, Producto>();
        }

    public void agregarProducto(Producto producto){

            Producto productoActual = this.listaProductos.get(producto.codigo);


            if (productoActual != null) {
               productoActual.setCantidad(productoActual.getCantidad() + 1);
            } else {           
               this.productos.put(producto.getCodigo(), producto);
         }
        }
//    [...] Los demás metodos...
    }
```